# Can parallel universes constitute the missing mass aka dark matter?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, multiverse

If parallel universe theory is true and if indeed there is gravitation leakage from 1 universe to the other, there would be infinite number of universes and thus unimaginable amount leakage would occur making life or formation of any matter impossible.

Does that sound like a plausible answer?

Comment: Dark Matter isn't the missing mass. It's the excess mass.

Comment: see http://cdms.berkeley.edu/Education/DMpages/FAQ/question32.html - the assumption is that leakage is short-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase *parallel universe* is a rather general one covering a wide range of speculative theories. The closest I know to a quantitative theory is the [ekpyrotic model](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1245). This provides a way of account for [dark energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy), though not for dark matter.